# Can limit go inside the integral if sequence has only one point of non uniform convergence?

Tags: uniform-convergence

> Let $\displaystyle  f_{n}(x) =\frac{1}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$.Which of the following are true?
>
> 1) $f_{n}$ converges pointwise on $[0,1]$ to a continuous function.
>
> 2) $f_{n}$converges uniformly on [0,1].
>
> 3) $f_{n}$ converges uniformly on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.
>
> 4) $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1}(\displaystyle  \lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x)) dx.$

Using $M_{n}$ test we can prove this series is not uniformly convergent. And point of nonuniform convergence is 0. Hence we can say it will be uniformly convergent on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ but since it is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ can we say 4th option is not true?

Comment: I believe you that $f_n(x)$ convergence uniformly to $f(x)=\lim f_n$ on $[1/m,1]$ for every $m$, if that is so, you know that $\int_{1/m}^1 f_n dx\rightarrow \int_{1/m}^1 f dx$ for every $m$, I believe this implies that $\int_0^1 f_n dx$ convergence to $\int_{0}^1 f dx$ becuse the functions are bounded.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to calculate $\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) dx$ and $\int_{0}^{1}(\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n}(x)) dx$.

Then you can check if option 4 is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this case
$$\int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}x^{2}},dx=\frac{1}{n}[\arctan(nx)]_{x=0}^1=\frac{\arctan(n)}{n}.$$
What may we conclude about option 4?

More generally, if the sequence $(|f_n|)_n$ is uniformly bounded by $M>0$ in $(0,1]$ (in your case we can take $M=1$) and $f_n\to 0$ uniformly in $[a,1]$ for any $0<a<1$, then $\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx\to 0$. In fact, we have that for $\epsilon>0$, eventually
$$\left|\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx\right|\leq  \int_{0}^{\epsilon/(2M)} |f_n(x)| dx  +\int_{\epsilon/(2M)}^1 |f_n(x)| dx\\\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2M}\cdot M+\int_{\epsilon/(2M)}^1 |f_n(x)| dx
\leq  \frac{\epsilon}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}= \epsilon$$
where in the final step we used  the uniform convergence in the interval $[\epsilon/(2M),1]$.